# Extract JSON object inside of an JSON array then search base on ID

Tags: mysql, mariadb, json

I have a problem extracting data in the JSON column. I'm new to this JSON method, unlike relation tables.

**Sample Table:** every minute/second all websites activity will be saved in 1 column alongside timestamp.
[image]

**Expected Table:** I wanted to produce is to extract the object details of a specific id, so I can have a full table of that objects.

```
SELECT dtime, activity.id, activity.ssl, activity.online, activity.cert
FROM logs
WHERE activity.id = 3
```

[image]

**dbfiddle:**

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=7982cd1738b4fc594fb033403a492a6c

Comment: If this is a common action, the value should be in its own column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem.

1. Make sure you check the version if JSON functions are supported.

- MySQL8+
- MariaDB 10.6.0+

In my case, this was easily fixed by `JSON_TABLE` just like this post ["read json array on mysql query"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63001045/9682185)

```
SELECT 
  dtime, 
  get_activity.* 
FROM 
  logs, 
  JSON_TABLE(
    activity, 
    '$[*]' COLUMNS (
      `id` int(11) PATH '$.ID', 
      `ssl` int(1) PATH '$.SSL', 
      `online` int(1) PATH '$.Online', 
      `cert` text PATH '$.Cert'
    )
  ) get_activity 
WHERE 
  get_activity.id = 3;
```

All Result:

[image]

Result using **WHERE** filter:

[image]

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=dffc098c0ec9711d391abdd7289af441)

Comment: What if we don't have static/certain column names/keys? Can we make a dynamic structure kind of loop or something?